# Registering Jscript on a Tridion-generated page

Tags: 2013, templating, c#

I'm attempting to register some javascript on a Tridion-Generated page via a user control.
I've created a page object that uses a generic aspx page template.
The TBB for the page template contains only the registration for the usercontrol and `<!-- TemplateBeginRepeat name="Components" --> @@RenderComponentPresentation()@@ <!-- TemplateEndRepeat -->`. 
The Component Presentation contains 1 component that calls a cp  that has an associated tbb that calls the usercontrol.
In the usercontrol is the following code:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         if (Request.QueryString["ID"] == "56")
        {
            ltrClassName.Text = "active";
            ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;
            StringBuilder jscript = new StringBuilder();

            jscript.Append("<script type=text/javascript> alert('Hello World!') </");
            jscript.Append("script>");

            cs.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "PopupScript", jscript.ToString());

        }
        else
        {
            ltrClassName.Text = string.Empty;
        }
    }
```

When I view the published page and add ID=56 as a parameter to the url, I get 'active' and nothing else.  The jscript is not part of the source.

Any reasons why this will not work with Tridion?

Comment: This should work fine. Is your component template dynamic? Make sure it is set to "Published Embedded on a page" (static).

Comment: "The Component Presentation contains 1 component that calls a cp that has an associated tbb that calls the usercontrol." could you elaborate? How does a component call a CP which calls a usercontrol? Which code is being executed at which point (render/request)?

Comment: The component template has a related tbb that contains a usercontrol tag. When the page is called with the 56 id, 'the ltrClassName.Text = "active";' runs as it should.

Comment: If dynamic it could still work if the is DCP on the file system as an ascx file, right? Otherwise make sure the CT is checked in and the changes are published.

Answer (score 2):

I would venture to guess this is not in any way related to Tridion but is in fact a fairly generic .Net related question.

Perhaps [this explanation](http://codewala.net/2011/11/24/page-clientscript-registerstartupscript-is-not-working/) will help? Or in code:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "PopupScript", "javascript:alert('Hello World!');", true);
```

Comment: Tried the above with the same results.

Comment: Tried the above with the same results. FYI-when I create a test page using the same setup(page that calls a usercontrol--same code in the usercontrol) it works as it should using cs.RegisterStartupScript.

Comment: So the published page from Tridion (which should be an .aspx file) and your test page are identical (bit for bit) and it works only on your test page?